# FlaskのTemplateを編集しても更新されません

Tags: python, flask

https://github.com/cyrilrbt/canadian-nutrient-file

上記のリポジトリをCloneして使おうと思っていますが、Templateを編集しても更新されません。もちろんサーバーを再起動してます。

後、起動の仕方もRepoの説明ではなく、

```
python cnf/main.py runserver
```

を

```
Project/canadian-nutrient-file$
```

のメインフォルダーから起動してます。
単に"Hello World"的なフレーズを加えて試しているのですが、画面に表示されません。

プロジェクトのフォルダーTreeはこんな感じです：

```
├── base.cfg
├── bin
│   ├── buildout
│   ├── cnf
│   ├── pip
│   ├── pip3
│   ├── pip3.7
│   ├── python
│   └── wheel
├── bootstrap.py
├── buildout.cfg
├── canadian_nutrient_file.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── entry_points.txt
│   ├── not-zip-safe
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── requires.txt
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── cnf
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── scripts.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── templates
│   └── views.py
├── cnf_csv
│   ├── CONVERSION FACTOR.csv
│   ├── FOOD GROUP.csv
│   ├── FOOD NAME.csv
│   ├── FOOD SOURCE.csv
│   ├── MEASURE NAME.csv
│   ├── NUTRIENT AMOUNT.csv
│   ├── NUTRIENT NAME.csv
│   ├── NUTRIENT SOURCE.csv
│   ├── REFUSE AMOUNT.csv
│   ├── REFUSE NAME.csv
│   ├── YIELD AMOUNT.csv
│   └── YIELD NAME.csv
├── CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
├── CONTRIBUTING.md
├── develop-eggs
│   └── canadian-nutrient-file.egg-link
├── eggs
│   ├── coverage-4.4.1-py3.7.egg
│   ├── Flask-0.12.2-py3.7.egg
│   ├── flask_mongoengine-0.9.3-py3.7.egg
│   ├── Flask_Script-2.0.5-py3.7.egg
│   ├── Flask_Testing-0.6.2-py3.7.egg
│   ├── mongoengine-0.13.0-py3.7.egg
│   ├── nose-1.3.7-py3.7.egg
│   ├── pylint-1.7.0-py3.7.egg
│   ├── python_dateutil-2.6.1-py3.7.egg
│   ├── setuptools-33.1.1-py3.7.egg
│   └── zc.buildout-2.13.3-py3.7.egg
├── LICENSE
├── MANIFEST.in
├── parts
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── pip-delete-this-directory.txt
│   └── webpy
└── versions.cfg
```

何かしらヒントもらえれば幸いです。

Main.pyはBootstrapを足して、`def main()`を`if __main__=="__main__":`
に変えました。

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from flask_script import Server, Manager
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

import cnf.settings
import cnf.scripts


# pymongo has issues...
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning, module='mongoengine')


def setup_app():
    app = Flask(
        __name__,
        template_folder=cnf.settings.TEMPLATE_FOLDER,
    )
    app.config.from_object(cnf.settings)
    with app.app_context():
        app.db = MongoEngine(app)
        app.bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
        app.manager = Manager(app)
        app.manager.add_command(
            'runserver',
            Server(
                host=app.config['FLASK_BIND'],
                port=app.config['FLASK_PORT']
            )
        )
        app.manager.add_command('import', cnf.scripts.Import())

    return app

'''
def main():  # pragma: no cover
    app = setup_app()

    # Import your views!
    with app.app_context():
        import cnf.views
    #app.run()
    app.manager.run()
'''

if __name__== "__main__":  # pragma: no cover
    app = setup_app()

    # Import your views!
    with app.app_context():
        import cnf.views
    #app.run()
    app.manager.run()
```

Comment: 単純には python cnf/main.py runserver としたら import cnf.settings の行がエラーになるだろうと思うのですが、何か書き換えたりしてませんか?

Comment: エラーは発生しませんが、Template上加えた文字が表示されません。それ以外は`from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap` と上記質問を編集ましたが、main.pyはBootstrap関連以外は書き換えていません。

Comment: すみません、`def main()`をコメントアウトして`if __name__=="__main__":にしました。